# Apache2 SSL Configuration with Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 14.x

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, virtualhost

I would like to have ONLY https traffic.  I want all of it to be driven to https://example.com and https://www.example.com.

At present this is what works and doesn't work:

https://www.example.com - ok!
http://www.example.com - shows a list of files in my webroot for some reason
https://example.com - This site can’t be reached / example.com refused to connect.
http://example.com - The example.com page isn’t working. example.com didn’t send any data.

I am using Ubuntu 14 (trusty) and here is my current enabled virtual host config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
       <VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443>
               ServerAdmin info@example.com
               ServerName www.example.com:443
               ServerAlias example.com:443

               DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

              SSLEngine on
              SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
              SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

              <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                              SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
              </FilesMatch>

              <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                              SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
             </Directory>
             BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
             # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
             BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
     </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any help much appreciated as going nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried made permanent redirect? https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

Comment: Thank you.  I hadn't enabled 000-default.conf and also the config was not correct.  I added below to 000-default.conf and enabled it and it works.  Much appreciated!

    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/

Comment: Seems only my top page works and all other pages below it now say, "Not Found

The requested URL /phpinfo.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.example.com Port 443

Comment: Sorry, it works.  I had to change all my external resource to pull in from https.  Thanks!